# when running the script from admin account the command $env:LOGONSERVER did not work?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get logon to server on my clients, it's working when running the command as logged-in user, but when running the script from admin account the command $env:LOGONSERVER did not work, result is nothing.
Is there another way to do this from admin account ?
Example

```
IF ($env:LOGONSERVER -eq '\\SRV001') {   }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you remove the \\ and use SRV001 instead ?

Comment: Don't, use pictures to show code. The picture does not match what you are asking for anyway. PowerShell only runs in the context of the user who started it. Meaning, the user profile in use. You cannot run PowerShell code on a remote host as the logged-in user. This is a Windows security boundary. You'd have to use other tools to do this. You can look at the logon events in the event viewer to get the logon server or use WMI to get computer information.